# Trying to understand the Redux action creators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

```
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  dispatch(showLoading(true));
}
```

this works fine

while this throws an error

```
export const loginUser = userData => {
    dispatch(showLoading(true));  // dispatch undefined
}
```

If I understand correctly, the 1st code snippent is the equivalent of

```
function loginUser(userData) {
   // dispatch is available here since its taken as a param for this inner function
    return function(dispatch){ 
        dispatch(showLoading(true));
    }
}
```

this means that dispatch is available in the loginUser function here.
Then why is the not available in the second code snippet.

Comment: because 2nd code is having a single function, not function returning function (2 functions as you have mentioned in first and last snippet). `dispatch` will be passed as an arg to 2nd functions and 2nd snippet don't have a 2nd function.

Comment: the equivalent code should return the inner function

Comment: you didn't define dispatch in your 2nd example

Comment: Action creator must return a function with dispatch arg. In second snippet it is missing. that's why you are getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow function equivalent of

```
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  dispatch(showLoading(true));
}
```

is

```
export function loginUser(userData) {
   return function(dispatch) {
      dispatch(showLoading(true));
   }
}
```

and when you execute your `loginUser` function, its executed like

```
loginUser(userData)(dispatch);
```

and hence `dispatch` is the argument to the inner function being called and not available as a value inside the outer function.

Thus in your example

```
export const loginUser = userData => {
    dispatch(showLoading(true));  // dispatch undefined
}
```

`dispatch` is undefined

Comment: thanks, the call loginUser(userData)(dispatch); cleared up things

Comment: Additionally we have to say that it is possible when you are using `redux-thunk` middleware which allows you to return functions from your actions, other way it must return plain object.